# Remove any content between head tags when parsing with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have already searched but have not found an appropriate reply.

```
url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bryan_Greenberg"
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
try:
    ourUrl = opener.open(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(ourUrl)
except Exception,err:
    continue
dem = soup.findAll('p')
```

I have just copied a part of the script. How can i remove all the content that is placed in title and head tags. So it doesn't come in soup. Thanks you.

Comment: Why do you want to remove that content? It seems to me when scraping an HTML file I'm more interested in finding a small subset of the web page to take and use than in finding parts of it to not use.

Comment: I want everything else. But i want to remove ANYTHING in the head tags

Answer (score 1):

I do not have BeautifulSoup installed so it is untested but should do the trick I guess:

Use [extract()](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) method:

```
markup = '<a href="http://example.com/">I linked to <i>example.com</i></a>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup)
a_tag = soup.a

i_tag = soup.i.extract()

a_tag
# <a href="http://example.com/">I linked to</a>
```

where in place of `soup.i.extract()` put your unwanted tag name like `soup.head.extract()`. Be aware that this may remove all the head or title tags from the document (if there happen to be any extra tags), I simply do not know exactly as have never used this function.